# Laravel Cron Scheduler job not running as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have Laravel cron issue ,In  Console Kernel I have defined job which will hit Rollovercron.php file every 10 mins and every time it will hit it will pass one country. atleast 100 Countries are defined in an array and will be passed one by one to Rollovercron.php according to foreach loop. Rollovercron.php file takes minimum 2 hrs to run for single country.

I have multiple issues with this cron job:

1. 100 elements in an array not getting fetched one by one means I can see 'GH' country(Ghana) has run for 5 times continuously and many of the countries are  skipped.
2. when ever I get country missing issue I  do composer update and clear cache frequently.

I want my cron should run smoothly and fetch all countries not even single country should miss and I should not need to do composer update for this all the time.

Please help me in this ,struggling for this since many months.

bellow is Kernel.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

use DB; 

class Kernel

extends ConsoleKernel

{  


/**

* The Artisan commands provided by your application.

*

* @var array

*/

protected $commands = [

\App\Console\Commands\preAlert::class,

\App\Console\Commands\blCron::class,

\App\Console\Commands\mainRollover::class,

\App\Console\Commands\refilingSync::class,

\App\Console\Commands\TestCommand::class,

\App\Console\Commands\rollOverCron::class,

\App\Console\Commands\FrontPageRedis::class,

\App\Console\Commands\filingStatusRejectionQueue::class,

\App\Console\Commands\VesselDashboardRedis::class,

\App\Console\Commands\Bookingcountupdate::class,

//   \App\Console\Commands\Voyagetwovisit::class,

];

/**

* Define the application's command schedule.

*

* @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule

* @return void

*/

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)

{


$countrylist=array('NL','AR','CL','EC','DE','PH','ID','TT','JM','KR','BE','VN','US','BR','CM','MG','ZA','MU','RU','DO','GT','HN','SV', 'PR','SN', 'TN', 'SI','CI','CR','GM','GN','GY','HR','LC','LR','MR','UY','KH','BD','TH','JP','MM','AT','IE','CH','LB','PY','KE','YT','TZ','MZ','NA','GQ','ME');


foreach ($countrylist as $country) { 

$schedule->command('rollOverCron:send ' . $country)

->everyTenMinutes()

->withoutOverlapping();



}

foreach ($countrylist as $country) { 

$schedule->command('mainRollover:send ' . $country)

->daily()

->withoutOverlapping();



}

$schedule->command('filingStatusRejectionQueue')

->hourly()

->withoutOverlapping();





$schedule->command('Bookingcountupdate')

->everyTenMinutes()

->withoutOverlapping();






$schedule->command('preAlert')

->hourly()

->withoutOverlapping();




}
protected function commands()

{

require base_path('routes/console.php');

}

}



/**

* Register the Closure based commands for the application.

*
* @return void

*/
```

Comment: Do you somehow mark the countries that have already been processed? Otherwise your `foreach` will always start with the same countries. And maybe your Rollovercron.php should handle all countries and you should not use `foreach` in the Kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel scheduling, knowing how it works helps, so you can debug it when it doesn't work as expected. This does involve diving in the source.

You invoke [command](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Schedule.php#L85) on the scheduler, this returns an [event](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Schedule.php#L132).
Let's check how Laravel decides what defines [overlapping](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Event.php#L627), we see it expires after 1440 minutes, aka [24 hours](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps).
So after one day, if the scheduled items have not run these scheduled items just stop being scheduled.
We see that a [mutex](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Event.php#L636) is being used here. Let's see where it comes from. It seems it's provided in the [constructor](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Event.php#L165).
So lets see which mutex is being provided. In the [exec](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Schedule.php#L132) and the [call](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Schedule.php#L72) functions the mutex defined in the [Scheduler](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Schedule.php#L53) constructor is used.
The mutex used there is an interface, probably used as a Facade, and the real implementation is most likely in [CacheSchedulingMutex](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/8ffd2310a60472ed060594824fd231924a8a2c2c/Scheduling/CacheSchedulingMutex.php), which creates a [mutex id](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/8ffd2310a60472ed060594824fd231924a8a2c2c/Scheduling/CacheSchedulingMutex.php#L45) using the [mutexName](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Event.php#L207) from the event and the current time in hours and minutes.
Looking at the [mutexName](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Scheduling/Event.php#L207) we see that the id exists out of the expression and command combined.

To summarise, all events called in one Scheduler function, share the same mutex that is used in checking if method calls don't overlap, but the mutex generates an unique identifier for each command, including differing parameters, and based on the time.

Your scheduled jobs will expire after 24 hours, which means that with jobs that take 2 hours to complete, you'll get about 12 jobs in a day completed. More if the jobs are small, less if the jobs take longer. This is because PHP is a single threaded process by default.
First task 1, then task 2, then task 3. Etc... This means that if each tasks takes 2 hours, then after 12 tasks their queued jobs expire because the job has been running for 1440 minutes and then the new jobs are scheduled and it starts again from the top.

Luckily there is a way to make sure they run [simultaneously](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#background-tasks).

I suggest you add `->runInBackground()` to your scheduling calls.

```
$schedule->command('rollOverCron:send ' . $country)
        ->everyTenMinutes()
        ->withoutOverlapping()
        ->runInBackground()
        ->emailOutputTo(['ext.amourya@cma-cgm.com','EXT.KKURANKAR@cma-cgm.com']);cgm.com']);
    }
```

Comment: ,Thanks for fast reply ,You mean If I use runInBackground() command my all countries from an array will execute ,I'll not miss even single country.

Comment: that's the idea yes. They will be executed simultaneously, without waiting in a queue. Well I Imagine, 1 will run on first cron call, 2nd on second cron call etc.. so they are all individual processes

Comment: Thanks it really worked for me. No country missing issue is coming.

Comment: What do you mean with No country missing issue is coming?

Comment: @Tschallackya I mean after using runInBackground() command my all countries from an array is executing ,I am not missing even single country.

Comment: I have used runInBackground() , It's bringing data but made my application very slow.Is there any other way so that  My application run in background  but doesnot bring load on mysql table.

Comment: @ext.vsahu if you don't want to put a load on your mysql, I suggest you do the heavy reading from a slave sql server, and only perform the writes as one big transaction on the master table when all the data is prepared.

Comment: we already implemented Master Slave configuration . writes are happening in Master database and Read is happening in Slave database.So problem occurs when I run cron script in background for 80 countries(fetching from array), that time 80 session initiates and start reading in slave database , because of this slave database gets engaged and when we open application it goes slow as already 80 sessions are reading from it

Comment: ext.vsahu are the writes happening within a transaction though? I mean all the writes? The "actual" writing should only occur when the transaction is comitted when all the computing work is done. And unless we're talking about millions of records, it should commit fairly fast.